# Converter imagem para CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

É possível converter a imagem abaixo em `css` puro?

[image: Imagem relacionada.]

Se sim, como eu poderia fazer isso? Alguém tem um exemplo?

Preciso também que tenha aquela divisão, exatamente como na imagem.

Comment: Quando vc diz "Preciso também que tenha aquela divisão" o que exatamente vc quer dizer?

Comment: Wendler da para fazer apenas um uma div sim! Olha a edição que eu fiz na minha resposta que vc vai ver como ficou!

Comment: @hugocsl Show de bola, só me da mais uma dica. Como que eu poderia fazer para colocar mais dois números ali, um em cada retângulo, tudo na mesma DIV. Tentei fazer separando classes, mas deu problema por que o segundo retângulo usa o position:absolute, então cobre o texto.

Comment: Fiz com a seguinte classe: `.counter{color:#fff;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:60px;font-weight:700;letter-spacing:12px;line-height:63px;padding:0 0 0 6px;height:70px;margin-top:-1px;position:relative;width:105px}`

Deu certo no primeiro retângulo, mas no segundo não apareceu.

Comment: Wendler não precisa disso. Veja a edição que eu fiz no meu código, que vc vai entender. Já coloquei um número dentro de cada Div, não precisa usar position nem nada. Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema considere marca-la come resolvida `✔` assim mantemos os site organizado.

Comment: @hugocsl Na verdade já tinha tentando algo assim, problema é que naõ vai funcionar, pois o sistema gera os dois números dentro da div, não tem como eu separar eles.

Comment: Esses números são alterados sempre, é um cronometro regressivo.

Comment: Outra coisa, eu preciso que seja com a classe **counter**, exatamente com esse nome, pois o sistema busca informação através dessa classe.

Comment: O que vc quer já é uma pergunta diferente. Se vc tiver alguma outra dúvida crie uma pergunta nova. Essa eu já respondi, se quer uma coisa diferente do que pediu crie outra pergunta pq essa já está ficando bastante bagunçada e fora do escopo do que foi pedido. **marca essa** e abre outra pergunta que facilita.

Comment: Perfeito, fiz uma nova pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282706/problema-com-atr%C3%ADbuto-position-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: (apena uma `<div>`)** Da para fazer apenas com uma `div` sim, seguindo o mesmo princípio do usando o elemento `::before` e colocando o `backgrounde` `radial-gradient` em cada um deles.

- **OBS:** Para colocar o número dentro basta colocar 1 dentro da `<div>` e o outro dentro co `contente:""` do `::after`

Veja o exemplo com só uma `div`

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.retangulo {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at top left, blue 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 60%, blue 61%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150% 80%;
    background-position: top -10px left 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.65) inset;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 80px;

}
.retangulo::before {
    content: "2";
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at top left, blue 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 60%, blue 61%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150% 80%;
    background-position: top -10px left 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 51px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.65) inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="retangulo">1</div>
```

---

Da para fazer sim meu jovem, olha o resultado ai. Puro CSS!

Usei um box-shadow com inset para fazer o sombreamento escuro na parte de dentro, e um pseudo elemento ::after para fazer o "brilho" com um background radial gradiente

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}
.btn {
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.btn::after {
    content: "";
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -50px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(blue 30%, azure);
    opacity: 0.65;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="btn"></div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, o problema é que preciso fique tudo em uma div só, não em duas. Seria possível?

Comment: Wendler a olha a primeira parte da minha resposta com o **EDIT**, da para fazer só com uma `div` sim!

Answer (score 2):

É possível, sim! E eu diria que até simples.
Basta você desmembrar os elementos da figura para encontrar a solução completa.

Você poderia começar com:

```
<body>
  <div class="retangulo">
 </div>
</body>
```

E criar os estilos, primeiro o retângulo:

```
 .retangulo {
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 80px;
background-color: #0000ff;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Agora precisamos criar essa "luz" que sombreia a forma.
Alteramos o *HTML* para alocar o novo elemento:

```
<body>
    <div class="retangulo">
      <div class="shade"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

E *CSS* da sombra eu fiz assim, não tá exatamente igual ao original, mas fui só montando rapidinho:

```
.shade {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  left: -30px;
  top: -30px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
  opacity: 0.3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Ajuste o *CSS* conforme as suas necessidades!
Depois é só fazer o *HTML* pra ficar exatamente igual na imagem de referência.

Exemplo:

```css
.retangulo {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.shade {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  left: -30px;
  top: -30px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
  opacity: 0.3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="retangulo">
      <div class="shade"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Caique Romero Perfeito, o problema é que preciso fique os dois retângulos em uma div só, não em duas. Seria possível?